# How to sort a table items in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, sorting

I am new to xcode, i have been actively search online tutorial to do something like jquery sortable [link here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). The only difference my table items are in a single row, however i must be able to rearrange them like **item1|item3|item2|item4**. and i also also need to know the final sorting result of the array so i can use it to search the database. Anyone have idea how to do this in xcode? very appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tableView and reorder the cells of it:

```
#pragma mark Row reordering
// Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return YES;
}
// Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
        toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
     NSString *item = [arry objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [arry removeObject:item];
    [arry insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

But this is used for one item per row.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html